# How can I get Jenkins to archive git difference between last build and latest one?

Tags: git, jenkins

So basically I'm trying to get Jenkins to make an update.zip of all the changed files (including their path) between the last build git commit and the latest one.

I have this script to make a full files zip and an update zip however if I make multiple commits and push, it will only make an archive of the latest commit.

Is there any way I can get it to make an archive of all the changed and new files in the update zip from the previous build commit to the latest?

```
zip -r -9 $WORKSPACE/builds/full-files-$BUILD_NUMBER.zip files
git archive -o $WORKSPACE/builds/Update-$BUILD_NUMBER.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only HEAD^)
```

(Hopefully I'm explaining this correctly)

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to be able to retrieve the last commit built. According to the git plugin [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin), it should be available in the `GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT` environment variable. Hence you could try getting the diff using

```
git diff --name-only $GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT
```

Comment: Is that previous commit from the current pushed commits, so for example if I pushed 12 commits would previous commit be number 11 or would it be the one before the 12 commits were pushed?

Comment: It would be the commit before the current build. In your example it would be the one before the 12 commits were pushed.